# How can i integrate php with my Http-server?

Tags: php, http, webserver

Hi i've coded a web server using C language , a server just like apache or lighthttpd.
it does listenings on port 80 and manipulates with GET & POST requests, i may handle text/html files, but my question here : how can i integrate PHP compiler with it so i would be able to handle php scripts in my http-server, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to run it as a system call.

You can get documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php).

You will have to set the `$_SERVER` variables as environment variables for the call from values gleaned from the request header but then it should just be a matter of piping in the request body and returning STDOUT.

you should be able to do something similar to support other server side languages as well (python, ruby etc..)

Comment: yes it's all about setting env variables! i think there's something nammed FastCGI which is a good solution, but i don't know if i can use it under windows.